# Use types declaration on another package

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I have setup a private NPM registry hosting a fork of a publicly available package (which is allowed by the package's licence).

The source package has a type declaration provided by the wonderful DefinitelyTyped project.

Currently, in my project, if I write:

```js
import mypackage from '@private/mypackage'
```

The types provided by DefinitelyTyped (`@types/mypackage`) will not apply, and I will get the error:

> error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@private/mypackage'. 'node_modules/@private/mypackage/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

In my project, is it possible to redeclare the source package types for the fork, so that the above example will work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a declaration file (`.d.ts`) for the module:

```
declare module '@private/mypackage'
{
    import m from 'mypackage';

    export default m;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to import '@types/mypackage' instead of 'mypackage'

Comment: Important caveat: with this solution I must have both `mypackage` and `@private/mypackage` installed, otherwise I can't import from `mypackage`. Is there a way to use the type declarations without having to install both versions of the package?

Comment: @GnxR: It should not be required to install the package itself, you should only need the `@types` package. If this is not the case you either did not use a declaration file or your build tooling is doing something wrong. Using just `tsc` i can compile this without having the package itself installed.